# Get header with react over loadbalancer

Tags: reactjs, apache

is it possible in react to get the full header information when we have a loadbalancer between client and server?

In my example the client is opening the website. Normally i think we have a http request to the webserver. So in my example this request is going to the loadbalancer and then to the server and to the client.

So im looking to the header information and i dont have the header information from the loadbalancer.

Is that possible over react or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.